# Apple TimeCapsule 2TB (2013) real life expierience; store data next to backups?

Tags: time-machine, backup, time-capsule

Im having an old 2008 time capsule to store the backups of my system. Im planning to buy the new 2013 time capsule soon but need to know if it supports the following:

```
Backup data ( music, movies ) *beside the system backups without messing with them or    
deleting them in any way?
```

I have tried this with my 2008 model but it would sometimes wipe the data. 
Anyone can confirm this works correctly?

Also is the new wifi module really 3x times faster as claimed and in result backups your data a lot faster?

Answer (score 2):

Time Machine is the software that runs on your Mac so that won't change at all with the new device.

I would run a few manual backups from the command line on your existing Time Capsule to see what amount of data you are backing up and how long it takes:

```
 date; tmutil startbackup --block; date
```

Once you have a feeling for what your speeds are, you can start to determine what the bottleneck is. If your Mac takes too long to send the files itself due to a busy filesystem and CPU - no external upgrade will help. If you are waiting on the hard drive in the Time Capsule - that too is the same technology and you should expect minor speedups as the controller seems to be marginally faster in the new Time Capsule. Only if your bottleneck is the network speed between the Mac and the Time Capsule will the faster network make a difference for the time spent backing up.

The new antennas are working very well for cases where we have one or two machines at the edge of the wireless range - but we don't have many of the new Air that speak 802.11ac yet so although some speedup is possible - it's not as dramatic as the benchmarks show except in some limited circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is partition the Time Capsule hard drive. Before you activate Time Machine, you'll want to launch Disk Utility and partition the drive into two halves. Then choose one as your Time Machine drive and use the other to backup your music and movies the old fashion way.

Another option would be to purchase an additional external USB hard drive and connect it via the Time Capsule's USB port. It may be [a little wonky](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1583149), but it should work for your purposes.

ps: When I get home this evening, I'll update this post with screenshots to illustrate. And do a little more research on external drives.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how Disk Utility would partition a Time Capsule drive? I've not seen anyone accomplish that yet.